# What is a word for an employee who works at geographically different location than the rest of the team?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am aware of the word *remote*, but in these times, *remote* has come to mean people working from home. I am trying to distinguish that from someone who works at a remote location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not one word, but one generally refers to *an employee who works at geographically different location than the rest of the team* as a **field-office worker**, i.e., a person who works in a **field office** or **in the field**. From Lexico:

> **[field office](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/field_office)**: a subsidiary office located in the field, away from a main office or headquarters
>
> **[in the field](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/in_the_field)**: (of an employee) away from the home office; working while traveling

Answer (score 1):

I think ***[detached  employee](https://secure.ssa.gov/apps10/poms.nsf/lnx/0302001267)***  is the expression you are looking for:

> In the case of employment, under the agreement, a detached worker is an employee whose employer sends him or her from one country to work temporarily in the other country for the same employer or for an affiliate of that employer.

Comment: But what if the employee's location is in the same country as the rest of the team, just in a different city?